# Find the the entire set of elements of $R$, where $R := \mathbb{Z}_2[X] / (X^4 + X)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to find the the entire set of elements of $R$, where $R := \mathbb{Z}_2[X] / (X^4 + X)$.

Can someone confirm whether this answer I get is correct?

What I have done is used the congruence method, namely listing all possible elements up to degree 4 with coefficients 0 and 1, and then taken of ($x^4+x$) and if i can successfully take it off it is a duplicate, otherwise it is a true element of the ring. I got the following as elements:

$0, 1, x, x+1, x^2, x^2+1, x^2+x+1, x^2+x, x^3, x^3+1, x^3+x, x^3+x+1, x^3+x^2, x^3+x^2+1, x^3+x^2+x, x^3+x^2+x+1$

Comment: Do you know Modular Classes? If yes, try to paritition $\mathbb Z_2[X]$ into the modular classes induced by $X^4+X$

Comment: A good first example would be to consider $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(X)$. First thing is that we can write every polynomial $f$ of degree $\geq 1$ as $f=X g + c$ where $g\in \mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ and $c\in \mathbb{Z}$ (this is the euclidean algorithm). However, in the quotient we have $\overline{X}=\overline{0}$, thus, we get $\overline{f}=\overline{c}$. Thus, we have at most two elements in the quotient $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(X)$. Now we need to check, whether $\overline{1}=\overline{1}$ or not. Assume that they are the same, then this would mean that $1-0 \in (X)$ which is not the case. Thus, we have 2 element

Comment: In your case you should try to proceed the same way. You will get more elements as you a priori only kill polynomials of degree 4 and higher (as you quotient out $(X^4+X)$, ie the generator is of degree 4). Then you need to see which polynomials are left. There are not that many.

Comment: @Anvit Would you define what modular classes are please? I might know them by a different name.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I understand up to the part about 'in the quotient', would you be able to explain a bit further what this means?

Comment: $\mathbb N$ can be partitioned in to $k$ modular classes mod $k$, namely $0,1,2,\cdots,k-1$. That is, every Natural $n$ belongs to one of the classes listed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra) that is how you define $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(X)$ (or also your other quotient).

Comment: Or what is your definition of $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(X)$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Sorry I wasn't clear, I was referring to the X bar notation.

Comment: Ah I sorry, bar is the notation I use to denote the equivalence class. Ie. $\overline{f}=f + (X)$.

Comment: So the equivalence class of X is equal to the equivalence class of 0? What does this mean? (Sorry if its obvious!)

Comment: We have $\overline{f}=\overline{g}$ iff $f-g \in (X)$. Thus, you get $\overline{X}=\overline{0}$ (as $X-0 \in (X)$.

Comment: Ok, and then the part with 1(bar) = 1(bar) could you explain that a bit more please?

Comment: @Anvit I'm trying to go for your route as it links with some work we've been doing. I know that x is congruent to x^4 mod (X^4+X), but I'm not sure how I go about doing it for x^2 for example. Can you help me?

Comment: @Anvit can you check my solution in the question?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Can you check my solution in the question?

Comment: Looks fine to me :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Factor  $X^4+X$ as a product of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbf F_2[X]$ first; this polynomial has obvious roots $0$ and $1$, so polynomial division yields
$$X^4+X=X(X+1)(X^2+X+1).$$
(The last factor is irreducible because it is a quadratic polynomial without roots in $\mathbf F_2$.)

Next, use the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
\begin{align}
\mathbf F_2[X]/(X4+X)&\simeq\mathbf F_2[X]/(X)\times\mathbf F_2[X]/(X+1)\times\mathbf F_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)\\
&\simeq\mathbf F_2\times\mathbf F_2\times\mathbf F_2[X]/(X^2+X+1).
\end{align}

Comment: On the lower line, where you have the F_2 X X, what does that mean?

Comment: ???On the lower line, I have written the quotient of the polynomial ring $\mathbf F_2[X]$ by the ideal generated by the (irreducible) polynomial $X^2+X+1$.

Comment: I understand that, but you have written $\times \mathbf{F}_2$ and I don't know what the $\times$ is in this case, is it a product or something else?

Comment: I can't see that on my screen – or I misunderstand what you mean. Incidentally, if you mean a boldface F, it is obtained in math mode with  `\mathbf`.

Comment: Oh! I think I've got what you mean: it is the product of sets symbol (*times*).

Comment: I've put quotes around the $\times$ I'm not sure about

Comment: Ok, why is there one directly in front of each F? Why not just the one between each quotient?

Comment: I hadn't noticed the spurious $\times$. A typo, and I hadn't reread my post. Sorry for that. Is it clear now?

Comment: Ah yes it is now! Thank you haha that was very confusing!

Comment: On a side note, and sorry if it should be obvious now, but why have you just omitted the $[X]/(X)$ and $[X]/(X+1)$ from the line above?

Comment: Because each of these quotients is isomorphic to $\mathbf F_2$ by the *evaluation maps* $f(X)\mapsto f(0)$ and $f(X)\mapsto f(1)$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: can you check my solution in the question?

Comment: You have the correct number of elements (16) and there doesn't seem to be any duplicates. B.t.w. I had understood they asked  you the number of elements, not the list, so using the Chines remainder theorem doesn't simplify the solution.

Comment: Oh that's my fault sorry, I needed to find the entire set including the number. Thank you for responding again!